# Javascript private methods and private class variables

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm not a professional Javascript dev, so my experience is limited to personal projects using tutorials online as well as trial and error. I've just recently had the need to create an object that has its own methods and member variables etc. I've been reading Doug Crockford notes and others stuff but I'm struggling to understand how it all fits together.

Consider the following code:

```
var CLASS_VAR = "some_val";

function MyClass(opts) {
    this.options = opts;
    this.myContainer = null;
}

MyClass.prototype.doIt = function() {

    var privateMethod = function(options) {
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        // use CLASS_VAR and 'options' in some way
        return container;
    }

    this.myContainer = privateMethod(this.options);
}
```

This is essentially the pattern that a portion of my code is using, but I just don't know if it's efficient or proper. Is this pattern a good idea, or are there more sensible/efficient/correct ways of achieving the same thing? In my actual code, there is more than one private function in `doIt`. Also, there is ~50 "class" variables in the actual code, so should I keep these in the global scope, or is there some way to make them private class variables as in Java `private static final`?

**Edited to reflect first comment**

Comment: In your second block of code, that last `console.log()` call would **not** print `null`.  Are you sure you didn't originally write `console.log(this.myContainer)`?

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no valid reason to declare that `privateMethod` inside `doIt`. The code would be much more efficient without it, since as it is right now, `privateMethod` is redeclared on every invocation, but more importantly it doesn't seem to add any structural value or efficiency.

Comment: @Pointy I'm sorry you're right, I did originally have `this.myContainer`, I'll update the question. I suppose I'm just wondering if the original code block is bad practice or inefficient in some way.

Comment: @plalx well that's really what I was asking, I suppose. You see, I actually have 4 or 5 functions inside `doIt` (obviously its not called that) and those functions are a lot longer than the example. If I was to extract them all and dump everything into `doIt` it would be a bit of a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"@plalx well that's really what I was asking, I suppose. You see, I actually have 4 or 5 functions inside doIt (obviously its not called that) and those functions are a lot longer than the example. If I was to extract them all and dump everything into doIt it would be a bit of a mess."

Well, if the functions are only meant to be used inside `doIt`, you could do something like:

```
MyClass.prototype.doIt = (function() {

    function privateMethod(options) {
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        // use CLASS_VAR and 'options' in some way
        return container;
    }

    function someOtherPrivateMethod() {}

    return function () {
        this.myContainer = privateMethod(this.options);
    };
})();
```

Comment: Does this technique have advantages over the one in the question?

Comment: @RTF Definitely since it doesn't redefine the private functions on every `doIt` calls. Note that you can also call the private functions in the scope of the current object like `privateMethod.call(this)` rather than having to pass arguments to them.

Comment: They're also not private methods.  At best, they're mostly equivalent to private *static* methods, since they can't do anything with `this` unless you say like `privateMethod.call(this, options);`.  But they're not really even that, since they don't exist outside of their caller.

Comment: @cHao Well they are private in the sense that they are private to the caller.

Comment: @plalx: The "private" part is true enough.  :)  But i'd argue they're not private *methods*, as the behavior isn't actually attached to the object.  (You'd have to use `call` or `apply` to fake that.)

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, there aren't any 'real' private methods. The method 'privateMethod' is just a standard member of the 'doIt' method.

If you need to create real private members - The following is an excellent guide on Javascript Patterns (I recommend you start with the 'Revealing' pattern, and take it from there):
[Javascript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/)

Comment: There are no "real" private methods in JavaScript, but encapsulating a method inside another method is *every bit* as "private" as putting the private function outside the public function and closing over it.

Comment: @meagar - right, I missed that..thanks for pointing it out (-!